# Why does flutter's http.get function make the server return http error code 409? Invoking the exact same url on the browser returns status code 200

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart

My Flutter method that makes the http request. It even prints out the http url and invoking this same exact url on the browser returns status code 200 yet calling it programmatically using flutter's http.get returns error code 409.

```
 Future<String> saveUser(String firstName, String lastName, String sex) async {
    String url = domain +
        'register?' +
        'first_name=' +
        firstName +
        '&last_name=' +
        lastName +
        '&sex=' +
        sex;
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
      return response.body;
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      return 'Failed to Register User';
    }
  }
```

This is flutter's console log. the number represents the error code, and the 'script' tags represent the response body

```
I/flutter (27919): http://filteredkenya.co.ke/baliach/register?first_name=Tyler&last_name=Mutai&sex=Male
I/flutter (27919): 409
I/flutter (27919): <script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>
```

This is my Laravel's Controller method that's supposed to save data to DB and return a response (Has been mapped to both get and post methods):

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        //Validation:
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|min:3',
            'sex' => 'required|string|min:3',
        ]);

        //If there is an error in either one of the inputs
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }
        $registration = new Registration;
        $registration->first_name = $data['first_name'];
        $registration->last_name = $data['last_name'];
        $registration->sex = $data['sex'];
        $registration->save();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Comment: Strange, because `print((await http.get('http://filteredkenya.co.ke/baliach/register?first_name=Tyler&last_name=Mutai&sex=Male')).statusCode);
` prints 200 for me.

Comment: It seems that you are making a REST API. Why aren't you saving new users using the POST method?

Comment: I think that you are setting the 409 HTTP status code yourself somewhere in your code.

Comment: @RichardHeap Could it be as a result of the device I am using for testing? It's an Android phone running Android 7.1

Comment: @RichardHeap Never mind, I tried using different networks to test the flutter app. Turns out that my home wifi network is in someway resulting to a 409 error. I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my home wifi network is in some way resulting to an error 409 on the server. Testing the app on a different network yields correct results (Http Status Code 200). Why this happens, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by changing the name of the url, if I had register.php I changed it to regis.php this made the variables refresh or something similar and it was solved.